# My Area conveter crashing when i click the button, i don't know why

Tags: android

I am just new to this and can't figure out what the problem I tried to make another function but that also didn't work
When I click the Button it crashes I don't know what is happening it didn't take the value from Edittext that I am thinking??
is there any way to fix the problem?

This is the Area converter  file

```
 public class AreaConvert extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

Spinner from;
Spinner to;
Button convert;
EditText value;
TextView answer;
double input;
double Value;
double ret;
String[] FROMTO = { "Square MM", "Square M", "Square CM", "Square KM", "Square MILES", "Square YARDS" };

AdapterView<?> adapterView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_area_convert, container, false);
    from = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.from); // Spinner From
    to = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.to); // Spinner to
    value = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.value); // EditText
    answer = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.answer); // TextView
    convert = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.convert); // button

    ArrayAdapter aF = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, FROMTO);
    from.setAdapter(aF);

    ArrayAdapter aT = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, FROMTO);
    to.setAdapter(aT);

    convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Double tot;
            Double amount = Double.parseDouble(value.toString());
            if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[4]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[3]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square miles")) && (to.equals("square km"))){
        ret = 1.60934 * 1.60934 * amount;
        
    }
    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[3]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[4]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square km")) && (to.equals("square miles"))){
        ret = 0.62137 * 0.62137 * amount;
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[4]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[1]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square miles")) && (to.equals("square m"))){
        ret = 1609.34 * 1609.34 * amount;
        
    }
    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[1]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[4]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square m")) && (to.equals("square miles"))){
        ret = amount / (1609.34 * 1609.34);
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[4]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[2]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square miles")) && (to.equals("square cm"))){
        ret = amount * 160934 * 160934;
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[2]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[4]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square cm")) && (to.equals("square miles"))){
        ret = amount / (160934 * 160934);
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[4]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[0]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square miles")) && (to.equals("square mm"))){
        ret = amount * 1609340 * amount;
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[0]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[4]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square mm")) && (to.equals("square miles"))){
        ret = amount / (1609340 * 1609340);
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[4]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[5]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square miles")) && (to.equals("square yards"))){
        ret = amount * 1760 * 1760;
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[5]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[4]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square yards")) && (to.equals("square miles"))){
        ret = amount / (1760 * 1760);
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[3]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[1]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square km")) && (to.equals("square m"))){
        ret = amount * 1000 * 1000;
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[1]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[3]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square m")) && (to.equals("square km"))){
        ret = amount / (1000 * 1000);
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[3]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[2]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square km")) && (to.equals("square cm"))){
        ret = amount * 100000 * 100000;
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[2]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[3]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square cm")) && (to.equals("square km"))){
        ret = amount / (100000 * 100000);
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[3]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[0]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square km")) && (to.equals("square mm"))){
        ret = amount * 1000000 * 1000000;
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[0]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[3]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square mm")) && (to.equals("square km"))){
        ret = amount / (1000000 * 1000000);
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[3]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[5]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square km")) && (to.equals("square yards"))){
        ret = 1093.6133 * 1093.6133 * amount;
        
    }
    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[5]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[3]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square yards")) && (to.equals("square km"))){
        ret = amount / (1093.6133 * 1093.6133);
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[1]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[2]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square m")) && (to.equals("square cm"))){
        ret = amount * 100 * 100;
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[2]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[1]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square cm")) && (to.equals("square m"))){
        ret = amount / (100 * 100);
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[1]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[0]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square m")) && (to.equals("square mm"))){
        ret = amount * 1000 * 1000;
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[0]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[1]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square mm")) && (to.equals("square m"))){
        ret = amount / (1000 * 1000);
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[1]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[5]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square m")) && (to.equals("square yards"))){
        ret = 1.09361 * 1.09361 * amount;
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[5]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[1]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square yards")) && (to.equals("square m"))){
        ret = amount / (1.09361 * 1.09361);
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[2]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[0]))){
        // if((from.equals("square cm")) && (to.equals("square mm"))){
        ret = (amount * 10 * 10);
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[0]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[2]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square mm")) && (to.equals("square cm"))){
        ret = amount / (10 * 10);
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[2]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[5]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square cm")) && (to.equals("square yards"))){
        ret = 0.01094 * 0.01094 * amount;
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[5]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[2]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square yards")) && (to.equals("square cm"))){
        ret = amount / (0.01094 * 0.01094);
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[0]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[5]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square mm")) && (to.equals("square yards"))){
        ret = 0.001094 * 0.001094 * amount;
        
    }

    if ((from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[5]) && to.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(FROMTO[0]))) {
        // if((from.equals("square yards")) && (to.equals("square mm"))){
        ret = amount / (0.001094 * 0.001094);
        
    }

    if (from.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(to.getSelectedItem().toString())) {
        ret = amount;
    }
 //                    answer.setText(Double.toString(ret));
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), Double.toString(ret), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

This is XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AreaConvert">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/from"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/value"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.167"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/to"
    android:layout_width="122dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textDirection="anyRtl"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/answer"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.674"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_width="169dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.683"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/answer"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.313"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/convert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="CONVERT"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/answer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/value" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post stacktrace and mark the crashed position.

Answer (score 0):

Please show us your crash log. There could be some other error but from what you've posted the error is probably here.

```
 Double amount = Double.parseDouble(value.toString());
```

Your `value` is an edittext, and you're trying to parse that into a Double. What you need to do is first get the string from that edittext

```
String editTextValue = value.getText().toString()
```

Then parse that to double

```
Double amount = Double.parseDouble(editTextValue)
```